# Draw a PNG Image on the Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a need to create an Image at run time and save it on the server. For the sake of example, lets say I'm creating just a basic rectangle. This rectangle image will be a .png file. How would I do this with C# code in an ASP.NET MVC 4 app?

I'm trying to learn how to draw basic images in C# however, I'm not sure where to start. Can someone point me to a basic sample of drawing a a rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample for you to start.

**Source:** [How to generate a PNG file with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585016/generate-a-png-file-with-c-sharp)

**MSDN:** [Bitmap Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx), [Graphics Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx)

```
using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(50, 50)) {
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b)) {
    g.Clear(Color.Green);
 }
  b.Save(@"C:\green.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(300, 50);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 1, 1, 298, 48);
// render the image to output stream
img.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
//clean up
g.Dispose();
img.Dispose();
```