# The type or namespace name 'Graphics' could not be found

Tags: c#, android

I'm working on a school project using the Monogame API and I'm pretty new to c#.

I have seen examples of people using a Graphics class to [draw on a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585016/how-to-generate-a-png-file-with-c).
However, when I've tried to do that I get "The type or namespace name 'Graphics' could not be found".

```
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(50,50, Bitmap.Config.Argb4444);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
```

Comment: I think that `Graphics` is not available in Mono:\ Because `System.Drawing.Graphics` is all about WinForms and GDI+.

Comment: Oh, this makes sense. Any idea what I could use instead?

Comment: I don't know, but displaying an image is looks like common taks, so I bet with docs and google this can be found easily

Comment: ok, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use `Graphics` in mono by adding a reference to the drawing library in my csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
// other references
<PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="4.5.1" />
// other references
</ItemGroup>
```

After adding the refrence to your csproj file, just remeber to restore your project for the reference to be loaded. You can do this by running the terminal command `dotnet restore` inside your project directory.